# Access the HttpRequest with Restfulie?

Tags: java

This seems like a straightforward question, but I can't find it in the Restfulie documentation nor is Google coming up with an example.

I've got a Resource defined, the method is getting invoked, but I need to get to the query parameters on the URL that was used, which presumably means getting to the HttpRequest. Anyone know how you do that with Restfulie?

```
@Resource
public class Subscribers
{

    private final Result result;

    public Subscribers(Result result ){
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Get
    @Path("/subscribers")
    public void get() {

        // Need to get at the query parameters here...

        result.use( json() ).from( "You got me" ).serialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
@Get
@Path("/subscribers")
public void get(@QueryParam("name") String name) {


}
```

your have to append the keys and values to the request URL. also you need to encode the values. 
`http://mydomain/subscribers?name=abcde`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was really hoping to get to a Map of some sort. My REST url can have a bunch of potential parameters, so the list of arguments to my get() method is going to be quite long... :( Ah well.